# Custom Client and Resources tables Identity Server 4

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, identityserver4

Using the next few lines of code, I managed to get what I wanted in my Identity Server database - in-database stored IS4 thingies. I thought that was what we were supposed to have.

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDB"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDB"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
```

These created bunch of tables, and properties in them, which we want to be **minimazed** to the ones we **need**.

After that, I went on to follow the next walkthrough: https://damienbod.com/2017/12/30/using-an-ef-core-database-for-the-identityserver4-configuration-data/. All in hopes of finding a way to keep Identity Server 4 operational, and creating custom tables and columns in the database.

I am a noobie in IS4, and programming generally, so please have an understanding if I do something wrong.

The final questions are: is it possible to have reduced tables and columns? Is it an accepted practise? If so, can anyone help with a link, advice, snippet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The EF creates the tables that are needed in order for Ids4 to function.   I would be surprised if you can fiddle with the tables it creates.   The point of using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework is that its set up to work as needed.   Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to add roles to Identity Server (please correct me if I'm wrong).
As a general rule, it's better to leave the Identity Server db structure as it is - that way you can easily upgrade when new versions come out.  For roles, you'll need to handle it on your webapp side.
Later quickstarts help you remove TestUsers and replace with entity framework data store.
You can also just use external identity providers and simply do claims transformations against your private user/role db rather than keeping users in Identity Server.

Comment: Look closer at Identity Server's AccountController methods - it uses different methods depending on what approach you're using.

Other than that, you'd have to be a lot more specific about what you need.

Comment: We are still discovering Identity Server 4, and waiting for that "Aha!" moment... Thank you all for your time, things are clearer.